# ReportViewer error on new server

Tags: iis, reportviewer, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

Since we moved to a new server we get the following error:
[image: The error]
We made an exact copy of all files of the site from the previous server (Server 2003 with IIS) and put it on the new server (Server 2012 with IIS). The application has been written in Silverlight 4.
The information the ReportViewer has to show is for really important daily analyses.
If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
It was the version of the ReportViewer where we first had version 10 and 11. Version 10 wasn't installed anymore. We fixed it by changing the web.config.